# Adding a custom method to the document object is 'undefined' in IE8

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8

For some reason the following code does not work as expected when in IE 8, as noted in the comment.  I'm trying to add a "writeSpecial" method to the document object, and this works fine the first time that the method is called, but whenever this is called a subsequent time, it becomes undefined.

However, this only happens in IE when I use the onload event.  There seems to be no difference between an inline body onload and window.attachEvent('onload', main);.  If I call main() directly from the script block, it works fine.  Again, this is only in IE.

Would anyone happen to know why this is?

Thanks!

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      document.writeSpecial = function(str)
      {      
        this.write(str + " [specialfied]");
      }          

      function main()
      {           
        alert(document.writeSpecial);
        document.writeSpecial('test 1');
        alert(document.writeSpecial);    //document.writeSpecial is undefined here in IE, works in firefox...why?
        document.writeSpecial('test 2');        
      }    
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="main()">
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some testing and as near as I can figure in IE `document.write` resets the `document` object.  So here is a revised version that will work.  If you didn't use the write function I don't think you would have had any trouble.  Maybe someone else can elaborate on why IE does this.

```
window.onload=function(){
function foo(str){
  document.write(str + " [specialfied]");
  document.writeSpecial=foo;
}
document.writeSpecial=foo;
main();
function main(){
  document.writeSpecial('test 1');
  document.writeSpecial('test 2');        
}};
```

Comment: A possible workaround (though I don't know for sure if it would work): Don't use document.write. Use `[body].innerHTML +=` instead.

Comment: It would work as well, but I'm not sure exactly what writeSpecial() is supposed to do so I'm not sure which is the better solution.

Comment: Thanks for the responses :). 

This is just an oversimplified example, taken out of context to illustrate what I had observed.  For all practical purposes, there are a few different ways that I can work around the issue.  I was mainly interested in an explanation for this behavior.